# TemplateDoesNotExist error-test en Tutorial Django

Tags: python, django, test

Estoy realizando el tutorial de Django y me ha surgido un error con el este test(creo que es el ultimo que se coloca):

`def test_past_question(self): past_question = create_question(question_text='Past Question.', days=-5) url = reverse('polls:detail', args=(past_question.id,)) response = self.client.get(url) self.assertContains(response, past_question.question_text)` este es el  enlace del tutorial: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial05/]

Y este es el error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/question_detail.html
```

Todo los demás test me funcionan.

De alguna forma, me junta `question_` con `detail.html`... ...pero no veo donde o como...
¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias adelantadas, en mi primera pregunta.

Comment: Django por defecto si tu no le especificas el template buscara en base a tu aplicacion y la funcion realizada en este caso es un detalle por ello buscara question_detail.html

Comment: Tomaré nota @Diego Avila. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Borré lo siguiente por error en `views.py`:
`template_name = 'polls/detail.html'`, de la `clase detail` que controla estas vista.

Lo que sucede, es que al no tener entonces la dirección, se la inventa. De ahí que generase esa `polls/question_detail.html`.

Comment: Amigo Fernando, gracias por esa pregunta y respuesta. Menos mal que no borraste tu pregunta me ha sido de gran ayuda, también tuve problemas con los test en mi aprendizaje y me quise hacer el valiente encontrando el error yo mismo....y no lo encontré. Muchas gracias y abrazo grande !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Fernando, el error está en eliminar la linea del `template_name = 'polls/detail.html'` en el Tutorial no se especifica muy bien si se debe hacer un reemplazo completo de esa clase `DetailView(generic.DetailView)` o si solo se le debe añadir la función de `def get_queryset(self)`

Al final el código en verdad debe quedar :

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```